# Meteor 1.4.2 TypeError: Cannot set property 'node_modules/react-router/package.json' of undefined

Tags: meteor, react-router

I'm suddenly getting this error in my Windows 8.1 console when trying to run an existing meteor project. I've tried "meteor reset" and "meteor update".  I've also tried deleting `\.meteor\local`. None of this has resolved the problem. I'm dead in the water.

```
C:\Users\mhl\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\templating-compiler\1.2.15\plugin.compileTemplatesBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\promise\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:177
      throw error;
      ^

TypeError: Cannot set property '/C/Users/mhl/Google Drive/Quarule/QREBuilder_Meteor_1.4/node_modules/react-router/package.json'
of undefined
    at Resolver._resolvePkgJsonMain (C:\tools\isobuild\resolver.js:321:9)
    at Resolver._resolve (C:\tools\isobuild\resolver.js:124:25)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\resolver.js:76:19
    at Entry._reallyRecompute (C:\Users\mhl\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\optimism\lib\entry.js:215:26)
    at Entry._recomputeIfDirty (C:\Users\mhl\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\optimism\lib\entry.js:179:17)
    at Entry.recompute (C:\Users\mhl\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\optimism\lib\entry.js:46:20)
    at Resolver.optimistic [as resolve] (C:\Users\mhl\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\optimism\lib\index.js:50:18)
    at ImportScanner._resolve (C:\tools\isobuild\import-scanner.js:459:36)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\import-scanner.js:492:29
    at _.each._.forEach (C:\Users\mhl\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:87:22)
    at ImportScanner._scanFile (C:\tools\isobuild\import-scanner.js:491:5)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\import-scanner.js:523:18
    at _.each._.forEach (C:\Users\mhl\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:87:22)
    at ImportScanner._scanFile (C:\tools\isobuild\import-scanner.js:491:5)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\import-scanner.js:523:18
    at _.each._.forEach (C:\Users\mhl\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:87:22)
    at ImportScanner._scanFile (C:\tools\isobuild\import-scanner.js:491:5)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\import-scanner.js:337:14
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ImportScanner.scanImports (C:\tools\isobuild\import-scanner.js:335:22)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\compiler-plugin.js:1037:17
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function.computeJsOutputFilesMap (C:\tools\isobuild\compiler-plugin.js:1005:19)
    at ClientTarget._emitResources (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:1006:8)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:777:12
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:359:18
    at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:352:34
    at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:350:23
    at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
    at ClientTarget.make (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:768:18)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2638:14
    at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2727:20
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\mhl\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2726:7
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:271:13
    at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:264:29
    at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:262:18
    at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:253:23
    at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.capture (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:252:19)
    at bundle (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2619:31)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2566:32
    at Object.withCache (C:\tools\fs\files.js:1597:12)
    at Object.exports.bundle (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2566:16)
    at C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:574:36
    at Function.run (C:\tools\tool-env\profile.js:490:12)
    at bundleApp (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:573:34)
    at AppRunner._runOnce (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:617:35)
    at AppRunner._fiber (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:876:28)
    at C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:403:12
```

Comment: Did you ever work out the cause of this? I've got this problem right now, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @mwarren Running `npm uninstall --save package && npm install --save package` fixed this for me

Comment: This is similar to [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41445266/whenever-i-import-the-node-instagram-module-meteor-crashes). See [my answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41803708/435004).