# Whenever I import the node-instagram module Meteor crashes?

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, instagram, instagram-api

I'm working on a Meteor app that uses the Instagram API. I added the node-instagram module which seems to be pretty up to date but when I added `import Instagram from 'node-instagram'` I get a crash starting the app. Any idea where I should look for the cause based on this output?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

```
    C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\templating-compiler\1.2.15\plugin.compileTemplatesBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\promise\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:177
      throw error;
      ^

TypeError: Cannot set property '/C/Users/Harry/WebstormProjects/ig-dash/node_modules/http/package.json' of undefined
    at Resolver._resolvePkgJsonMain (C:\tools\isobuild\resolver.js:320:9)
    at Resolver._resolve (C:\tools\isobuild\resolver.js:123:25)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\resolver.js:75:19
    at Entry._reallyRecompute (C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\optimism\lib\entry.js:215:26)
    at Entry._recomputeIfDirty (C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\optimism\lib\entry.js:179:17)
    at Entry.recompute (C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\optimism\lib\entry.js:46:20)
    at Resolver.optimistic [as resolve] (C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\optimism\lib\index.js:50:18)
    at ImportScanner._resolve (C:\tools\isobuild\import-scanner.js:466:36)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\import-scanner.js:499:29
    at _.each._.forEach (C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:87:22)
    at ImportScanner._scanFile (C:\tools\isobuild\import-scanner.js:498:5)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\import-scanner.js:577:12
    at _.each._.forEach (C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:87:22)
    at ImportScanner._scanFile (C:\tools\isobuild\import-scanner.js:498:5)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\import-scanner.js:577:12
    at _.each._.forEach (C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:87:22)
    at ImportScanner._scanFile (C:\tools\isobuild\import-scanner.js:498:5)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\import-scanner.js:577:12
    at _.each._.forEach (C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:87:22)
    at ImportScanner._scanFile (C:\tools\isobuild\import-scanner.js:498:5)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\import-scanner.js:577:12
    at _.each._.forEach (C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:87:22)
    at ImportScanner._scanFile (C:\tools\isobuild\import-scanner.js:498:5)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\import-scanner.js:530:18
    at _.each._.forEach (C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:87:22)
    at ImportScanner._scanFile (C:\tools\isobuild\import-scanner.js:498:5)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\import-scanner.js:344:14
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ImportScanner.scanImports (C:\tools\isobuild\import-scanner.js:342:22)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\compiler-plugin.js:1040:17
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function.computeJsOutputFilesMap (C:\tools\isobuild\compiler-plugin.js:1008:19)
    at ClientTarget._emitResources (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:1020:8)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:791:12
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:359:18
    at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:352:34
    at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:350:23
    at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
    at ClientTarget.make (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:782:18)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2652:14
    at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2741:20
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2740:7
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:271:13
    at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:264:29
    at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:262:18
    at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:253:23
    at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.capture (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:252:19)
    at bundle (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2633:31)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2580:32
    at Object.withCache (C:\tools\fs\files.js:1601:12)
    at Object.exports.bundle (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:2580:16)
    at C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:574:36
    at Function.run (C:\tools\tool-env\profile.js:490:12)
    at bundleApp (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:573:34)
    at AppRunner._runOnce (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:617:35)
    at AppRunner._fiber (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:876:28)
    at C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:403:12
```

Comment: It seems there are problems with this package. I think you should another one, [instagram-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-node) looks much better

Comment: Thanks @khang! That didn't fix it, in fact I had the same problem so I decided it was something related to the project. I started a new project but couldn't reproduce so I stripped out some of my projects npm packages and put them back, now it's fine. Will include my package.json diff in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

From my own investigation, this seems to be an issue with npm packages that have a `package.json` file but cannot be imported. For instance, this is the case of [the fake `fs` package on npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs).

In my own case, doing

`meteor npm uninstall --save fs`

solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue with both `node-instagram` and `instagram-node`, seems it was some issue with my installed npm packages. After fiddling around a little I got it working. In-case it's helpful, here is a diff of my *package.json*:

```
index 78ebc2e..ca65629 100644
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -7,9 +7,8 @@
   "dependencies": {
     "angular": "^1.6.1",
     "angular-meteor": "^1.3.11",
-    "babel-runtime": "6.18.0",
-    "http": "0.0.0",
-    "instagram-api": "^1.0.3",
-    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.0"
+    "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
+    "instagram-node": "^0.5.8",
+    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.2.4"
   }
 }
```

Comment: "http": "0.0.0", - this must be a mistake surely (or the cause of the problem)? My project uses http@1.2.10 (in .meteor/packages)

Comment: That's what was in my package.json but yeah it looks funky, not sure how it got that way.

Comment: For me it also says version 0.0.0 for http. Having the same problem and If I remove them and then doing `npm list` Im getting an error where http is missing.